# How can I time a MySQL query in C?

Tags: mysql

I use MySql through C and this goes OK.

Is here a way to get execution duration of the query?

Similar to the way we get "num_rows" or other related data in "mysql result".

Or I have to measure the time difference between the begining and the end of the execution?

Comment: Look at the MySQL API documentation. If there's a relevant function, use it; if not, use the measurement approach you mention being able to fall back on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, measure it yourself. The MySQL library doesn't do it automatically as this would be a resource drain — and an unfortunate one for those 99% of cases where we *don't* want the timings.

Comment: Well, that's relative. But OK, when I querry database through command window all results contains spended time so I thought that this may be also reachable through C API. Anyway, not a big problem. Thanx!

Comment: It's not relative. If MySQL did this then, for _everybody in the world_, processing time would be spent on it. 99% of the pair `(people, each person's time)` do not want that. The _vast_ majority of MySQL queries executed in the world are on production platforms with queries not being timed.

Comment: And yea I think the command-line client does that timing, so one layer higher than the actual DB API.